# Access Denied (windows.devices.usb, WinJS, Windows Store Apps)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winjs, device

I'm trying to build an app for managing content on either MTP devices or Windows Phones. However, as far as i've seen, **Windows.Devices.Portable.StorageDevice** does not offer the fine tuned capabilities in need to list *only* MTP Devices (or Windows Phones, since these are more important to me then MTP devices in general). As such, i tried passing the **windows.devices.usb.usbdevices.getdeviceselector()** aqs filter command through the **FindAllAsync()** device enumerator command, using the Vendor ID (VID) **0421** and Product ID (PID) **0661** (Where Windows Phone devices are registered). This seems to be fine and dandy, until I attempt to get the id of the first device in the list of devices within the **DeviceInformationCollection**, to which a "Access Denied" error is thrown.

Now, based on my recent experience with this error, it means i haven't defined the proper capabilities in the manifest. I already have defined:

```
<Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
<Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
<Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
<Capability Name="removableStorage" />
<DeviceCapability Name="usb" />
<DeviceCapability Name="6AC27878-A6FA-4155-BA85-F98F491D4F33" />
<DeviceCapability Name="EEC5AD98-8080-425F-922A-DABF3DE3F69A"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="BA0C718F-4DED-49B7-BDD3-FABE28661211" />
<DeviceCapability Name="6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F" />
<DeviceCapability Name="332ffe6a-af65-41e1-a0af-d3e2627bdf54" />
<DeviceCapability Name="0B9F1048-B94B-DC9A-4ED7-FE4FED3A0DEB" />
<DeviceCapability Name="A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED" />
```

In my research, MSDN says to use USB i have to define a class type under USB, like so, using the **classId**, class **name**, or device class GUID (**winUsbId**)

```
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
  <Device Id="vidpid:xxxx xxxx">
    <Function Type="classId:xx xx xx"/>
    <Function Type="name:xxxxx"/>
    <Function Type="winUsbId:xxxxx"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

However, they also state that among unsupported usages of classes is **Mass storage class**, and i haven't found a WPD or MTP class available.

I've tried many variations on commands, but any time i try to find the device id, it returns this error. For reference, here is the relevant code:

```
Enumeration = Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
UsbEnum = Windows.Devices.Usb;
MediaDev = Windows.Devices.Portable;
DeviceInformation = Enumeration.DeviceInformation;
```

---

```
// Get Windows Phones by VID & PID
        document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = ""; // clear output
        try {
            DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(UsbEnum.UsbDevice.getDeviceSelector("0421", "0661")).then(
                //Enumerate Storage Devices using IDs from UsbEnum
                    successEnum,
                    errorEnum);
            } catch (e) {
                document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "Failed to enumerate devices, error: " + e.message;
            }
```

---

```
function successEnum(winDevice) {
if (winDevice.length) {
    var firstDev = null;
    try {
        firstDev = winDevice.getAt(0).id;
        DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(MediaDev.StorageDevice.fromId(firstDev)).then(
            successCallback,
            errorCallback
            )
    } catch (e) {
        document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "Failed to enumerate devices, error: " + e.message;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
function successCallback(storageDevice) {
var winPhone = null;
if (storageDevice.length) {
    try {
        // Get a StorageFolder from the id for the first removable storage device
        winPhone = storageDevice.id;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = storageDevice.name; 
    } catch (e) {
        document.getElementById("statusMessage").innerHTML = "Error: " + e.message;
    }
    if (winPhone != null) {
        getImageFiles(winPhone);
    }
} else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
        "No removable storage devices were found.";
    }

}
```

---

Any help?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your whole question, but in your findAllAsync call, pass null as a second parameter. This is because there are two one-parameter overloads for findAllAsync, and the one that is projected into JavaScript accepts a DeviceClass arg rather than a selector, and when you give it a string it unfortunately devices to enum everything instead of throwing. So pass an extra null and you get the findAllAsync that takes a selector string. I pounded my head into a wall for a while on this one. That might help hone in on the rest of the problem.

Comment: I actually had a null in the argument, but removed it in case it was causing issues, since I was receiving the same error. However, thanks for the info. I'll put it back in to be safe.